# Git track a remote branch but push to a different branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Lets assume I have a branch called 'my-local-changes', which is a local branch, that was created from a branch called 'some-remote-branch', which is a remote branch.

Let's also assume there is a third branch called 'develop', which is the remote branch where code is pulled into from multiple branches ('some-remote-branch' is one of them, I also have a local branch called 'develop' that tracks the remote develop branch)

**My question is how can i set up 'my-local-changes' to track the 'develop' branch, but push to the branch 'some-remote-branch'?**

For those curious, as to why I want to do this, I would like to be able to run git status and see if I am behind 'develop' while not having to switch to that branch, and easily still be able to push to 'some-remote-branch'

My current process is as follows (I'd love any suggestions for improving this as well)

```
git checkout -b my-local-branch some-remote-branch
```

(make some changes and add them)

```
git fetch origin 
git checkout develop
git status
```

(do this to see if any changes on develop that I need to merge, if not run)

```
git push origin my-local-branch some-remote-branch
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Not sure why the question is downvoted,<sup>1</sup> and you have almost answered it yourself anyway...)

You are nearly there: simply configure `push.default` to `simple` or `nothing`, so that you *must* specify the push target for this case, and then for your final command, use:

```
git push origin my-local-branch:some-remote-branch
```

The way this works is that `git push` takes, after `origin` (the name of the remote), a series of *refspecs*.  A refspec is not very complicated: it's just a pair of names, like `master:master`, or `develop:develop`, or `develop:foo`, optionally with a leading plus sign `+`, and optionally omitting either the first or second name: `:foo` or `develop`.

Refspecs get slightly complicated in that they work differently in `git fetch` and `git push`, when you leave out one of the two names.  If you use both names each time, they stay simple: the name on the left is the name on the *source* repository, and the name on the right is the name on the *destination*.  For `fetch`, the source is the remote and the destination is your own repository.  For `push`, the source is your repository and the destination is the remote.

Leaving out the source name only works with `push`, and in this case, it means *delete*.  Hence `git push origin :foo` means *delete `foo` on remote `origin`*.  (That's not what you want, so avoid that.)

Leaving out the destination name works with both `fetch` and `push` but means different things to them.  Let's just ignore `fetch` here.  With `push`, it means *use the same name on both local and remote*.  Since you *don't* want that here, don't use it here.  (Or, for those cases where you *do* want it, go ahead and use it.)

The leading `+` sign, if present, means the same as `--force`.  (In fact `--force` just adds the `+` on everything.)

If you run `git push origin`, or `git push` (without even a *`remote`* argument), Git looks up `push.default` to see what to push.  Setting it to `nothing` means *just fail / error-out, so that I have to type in a refspec*.  Setting it to `simple` means *push just one branch, the current branch, to the current branch's upstream, but also require that the upstream name match*.  Since `my-local-branch` and `some-remote-branch` don't match, this will fail for your case of *local branch `foo` is tracking remote-tracking branch `origin/develop`*: the names `foo` and `develop` do not match.

Either way, Git will force you to enter a refspec for this push.

With the `nothing` configuration, Git will force you to enter a refspec for *every* push.  (I have used this and it works, but it's not terribly convenient.)  With the `simple` configuration, Git will allow you to push your `develop` to the upstream `develop` easily, and will allow you to push your `foo` to an upstream `develop` (or an upstream `jazzy`, or any other name but `foo`) explicitly, but won't push `foo` to `foo` since that's not its defined upstream.  (I have used this and it works better.)

**As of Git version 2.0, `simple` is the default configuration.**  So if you have Git version 2.0 or later, you are already good to go.  If not, see if you can upgrade your Git version, but `push.default` is configurable as far back as Git version 1.6.  (I'm not sure what values it could take on, then.  The current set-of-5 values goes back to 1.7.11 if not earlier, I think.)

For completeness, the other three possible values are: `current`, `upstream`, and `matching`.  The `current` value means use the current branch's name: `git push origin $branch:$branch` where `$branch` is the current branch.  The `upstream` value means use the current branch's upstream name: `git push origin $branch:$merge`, where `$merge` is from `git config --get branch.$branch.merge`.

The `matching` value is the hardest to describe, and was the default before Git version 2.0: it means *get a list of every branch on the remote, and match up their names and our local branch names, and then do an en-masse push of all of our local branches to the branch of the same name on the remote, wherever the two names match up.*  This is not a very safe setting, although as long as you do not use `--force`, it actually works pretty well in practice, which is why it was usable for so many years.

#### Side notes: terminology

Git's terminology is kind of a mess.

- A *local* branch (or just "a branch" or "a branch name"), like `master`, is a name in the `refs/heads/` name-space.  It points to a commit ID.  When you make a new commit while on that branch, Git reads the commit ID, makes the new commit with that ID as the new commit's parent, and then writes the new commit's ID into the branch-name, so that the branch now points to the new commit (which in turns points to the previous branch-tip, and so on).

  You can `git checkout` a local branch, which puts you on "on the branch", so that `git status` says `On branch master` for instance.  This sets things up so that new commits advance the branch, as I just noted above.
- A *remote-tracking branch* like `origin/master` is a name in the `refs/remotes/` name-space.  After `refs/remotes/` we find the name of the remote itself, `origin`, then another slash, and finally the name of the branch as seen on that remote (sans `refs/heads/` of course).  These names are stored locally, in your own repository: they're not actually remote at all.  They are just *automatically updated* when your Git contacts the remote, through `git fetch` and (to a more limited extent) through `git push`.

  You can `git checkout` a remote-tracking branch, but if you do, `git checkout` puts you in "detached HEAD" mode, so that `git status` and `git branch` claim you're not on any branch (or are on "no branch" or similar, sometimes using the "detached HEAD" phrasing).  When this happens you are actually on the (single, special) *anonymous* branch.  When you get back on a normal branch, any work you did on the anonymous branch will eventually fade away.  (So if you want to keep the work, set up a name, so that it's not anonymous anymore—or use `git checkout` to get back on a regular branch, before you do that work.)
- A local branch can *track* another branch (local *or* remote).  When local branch *B* is tracking another branch *U*, Git calls this the "upstream" of the local branch.  This upstream is composed of two parts: the name of the remote, like `origin`, and the name of the branch as seen on the remote, like `master`.  To track a local branch as your upstream for branch *B*, Git just sets the remote to `.` instead.

  Hence local branch *B* is tracking upstream *U* if it has these two items configured.  *U* is itself normally a remote-tracking branch, which is a local entity (one of those `refs/remotes/` name-space names).  You must `git fetch` or `git push` to get the remote-tracking branch(es) updated, after which `git status` and `git branch -vv` will report local branches that are tracking the remote-tracking branches, as being ahead and/or behind their counterparts.

  Local branch *B* can instead track another local branch as its upstream.  In this case, since everything is locally-updated, `git status` and `git branch -vv` will be up-to-date without any `git fetch` needed.

  A local branch *B* need not track anything, of course.  The commands `git branch --set-upstream-to upstream` and `git branch --unset-upstream` will set or unset the upstream of the current branch.  You can also set, change, and examine the two individual parts of the upstream (the `branch.$branch.remote` and the `branch.$branch.merge` parts) using `git config`, although using `git branch` is usually nicer and more convenient.

---

<sup>1</sup>Perhaps the downvote is because of the Git 2.0 default `push.default`.