# Git track different branches for push and pull?

Tags: git, push, pull, refspec, git-refspec

I have a Git repository which is being managed with Gerrit, where you don't push to `<branch>`, but instead push to `refs/for/<branch>`, and then *magic happens*. Thus, I'd like different behavior for `git pull` and `git push`. In particular, I want `git pull` to pull from `<branch>`, but `git push` to push to `refs/for/<branch>`. Is it possible to set this up in Git?

(Note: this has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110809/git-track-a-remote-branch-but-push-to-a-different-branch), but the answer was simply, "no, but here's how you can make Git force you to always specify the refspec so you'll never accidentally push to the wrong branch," which isn't the answer I'm looking for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following configuration:

```
 git remote add review ssh://user@review.example.com:29418/repo
 git config remote.pushDefault review
 git config remote.review.fetch master:master
 git config remote.review.push master:refs/for/master
```

I.e. add remote named `review`, set default push remote for all branches
to `review`, configure fetch/pull for `master` from remote branch `master`,
configure push for `master` to remote branch `refs/for/master`.

Comment: Ah, that's perfect; thanks! I was able to simplify it to `git config remote.origin.push HEAD:refs/for/master`.